Homebrew refuses to uninstall python while it is not required by other packages
I have python@3.13 installed and I want to uninstall python@3.12, I got the error
Error: Refusing to uninstall /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.7_1
because it is required by cairo, ghostscript, mactex, mono and pango, which are currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python@3.12

However, I checked that cairo does not require that by
brew deps --tree --installed cairo
cairo
├── fontconfig
│   └── freetype
│       └── libpng
├── freetype
│   └── libpng
├── glib
│   ├── pcre2
│   ├── python-packaging
│   ├── python@3.13
│   │   ├── mpdecimal
│   │   ├── openssl@3
│   │   │   └── ca-certificates
│   │   ├── sqlite
│   │   │   └── readline
│   │   └── xz
│   └── gettext
│       └── libunistring
├── libpng
├── libx11
│   ├── libxcb
│   │   ├── libxau
│   │   │   └── xorgproto
│   │   └── libxdmcp
│   │       └── xorgproto
│   └── xorgproto
├── libxcb
│   ├── libxau
│   │   └── xorgproto
│   └── libxdmcp
│       └── xorgproto
├── libxext
│   ├── libx11
│   │   ├── libxcb
│   │   │   ├── libxau
│   │   │   │   └── xorgproto
│   │   │   └── libxdmcp
│   │   │       └── xorgproto
│   │   └── xorgproto
│   └── xorgproto
├── libxrender
│   ├── libx11
│   │   ├── libxcb
│   │   │   ├── libxau
│   │   │   │   └── xorgproto
│   │   │   └── libxdmcp
│   │   │       └── xorgproto
│   │   └── xorgproto
│   └── xorgproto
├── lzo
├── pixman
└── gettext
    └── libunistring

and so does other packages stated in the error message (only python@3.13 is required).
Note that I have ran brew upgrade and brew doctor, there is no error with both.
What is going on here?

Sorry to use answers, but I can't comment so...
But have you tried uninstalling cairo and the others that are stopping you?
pip(3) uninstall cairo

And then afterward simply reinstall them?

Check in the reverse way, looks for who is using python@3.12.
brew uses --installed python@3.12


It returns cairo                          ghostscript                    mono                           pango
